# Limit of the function $\zeta(x)/\zeta(x+1)$ as $x \to \infty$

Tags: limits, special-functions, riemann-zeta

I am looking for a simple proof that $\zeta(\alpha)/\zeta(\alpha+1) \to 1$ as $\alpha \to \infty$ (where $\zeta(\alpha)$ denotes the Riemann zeta function, $\zeta(\alpha) = \sum \limits_{n\geq 1} n^{-\alpha}$).

*(Edit: Silly miscalculation by me, the terms do not go to 0 but in fact to 1, so the limit is easy to evaluate.)*  Since both terms go to 0, the limit isn't entirely trivial to evaluate. Also, since both terms are infinite sums of exponents I can't really use l'Hopital's rule without things becoming incredibly messy. Could anyone suggest an obvious way to show/see that the limit is 1 (as numerical evaluation would seem to indicate)?

Comment: Actually, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\zeta(x)=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dejan Govc points out, $\zeta(\alpha) \to 1$ as $\alpha \to \infty$. So clearly $\zeta(\alpha)/\zeta(\alpha+1) \to 1$ as $\alpha \to \infty$.

More interestingly, $\lim\limits_{\alpha\to\infty}\displaystyle\frac{\zeta(\alpha)-1}{\zeta(\alpha+1)-1}$ is equal to $2$, not $1$. But this is also easy to prove by comparing the first terms of each series.

Comment: Yes, stupid of me - I was for some reason thinking of a sum of increasing exponents of fixed $n$ in my head, rather than a sum of fixed exponents of increasing $n$. Thanks!